# Can not use the location object is javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I was making a page with frames.  One is a treeview frame, the other is showing a report. When I click the item in the left frame, the report will display in the right frame. But after I click the first item, the location object in the right frame became unavailable! Which prevents me from opening a new report in the same frame! Below is the main page code:

```
<iframe src ="demoFramesetLeftFrame.jsp" name="treeframe" id="treeframe" height="100%" width="200px" frameborder="0">
<iframe src="demoFramesetRightFrame.jsp" name="basefrm" id="basefrm" height="100%" width="" frameborder="0">
```

The basefrm is response for displaying the report.  Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the navigation from the left frame is taking the right frame to a page on a different hostname. Then the right frame's `window` properties including `location` are inaccessible to code in the parent page due to the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

You can still navigate a frame without using its window's `location` object. Just set the `src` attribute on the `iframe` object itself (in the parent document).

(Also consider not using frames for navigation like this. You'll be making your separate reports unbookmarkable.)

Comment: thank you bobince! Yes,the left frame is taking the right frame on a different hostname.but i have tested set the <code>src<code> attribute,it doesn't work.the right frame don't display the report at all.Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Setting `src` works fine for me, even on a frame that is currently displaying a document from a different domain. An alternative to allow navigation to still work if you don't have access to the report documents would be to have a series of pages, eg. `/report.php?report=1`, `/report.php?report=2`, each of which contains an `<iframe>` pointed at a single report, plus normal nav to go to the different parent documents.